# Ask for username until it's unique

Tags: python

I am still learning the basics of Python and I was trying to make a simple program which asks for a username and password and saves both in a file. What I have so far is this, I will only post the username function which is what is giving me a hard time:

```
username = str(input("Username: "))
with open('users.txt', 'r') as users:
for line in users:
content = line.split(',')
    while username == content[0]:
        print("Username already exists. Try again.")
        username = str(input("Username: "))
```

Let's suppose the users.txt file has the follow info:

```
user1,12345
user2,98765
user3,password1
```

I know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it. If I type user1 first, I get the error, then user3, error again but if I type user1 again it will accept it. This happens because it doesn't read through the beginning of file again, if there is no user1 after user3 it is validated. How should I solve this? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please ensure that you only use this for testing / coding assignments; storing passwords in a text document is *highly* insecure.

Comment: What you should do is read the entire file into a list at the beginning, then have your command operate on that list, then write the file back out at the end.  Note that `input` always returns a sting; you do NOT need to call `str()` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample architecture that will work:

```
def import_users(fn):
    u = {}
    for line in open(fn):
        name, pwd = line.strip().split(',')
        u[name] = pwd
    return u

def export_users(fn, ulist):
    with open(fn,'w') as users:
        for name,pwd in ulist.items():
            print(f"{name},{pwd}", file=users)

users = import_users('users.txt')

while True:
    username = input("Username: ")
    if username in users:
        break
    print("Username already exists. Try again.")
```

Obsidian Age is right that you would never do this in a real world situation.

Comment: Thank you, I did some modifications from your code but now it works as intended. Just a small correction if I may, in the last if statement I corrected for not in otherwise it would only accept usernames already existing in the file and my goal was to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet will prompt the user for every line which doesn't match.

Try moving the username checking logic into its own function:

```
def username_exists(username):
    with open('users.txt', 'r') as users:
        for line in users:
            content = line.split(',')
            if username == content[0]:
                return True
    return False

username = input("Username: ")
while username_exists(username):
    username = input("Username: ")
```